# PushViewController doesn't work - deinit called

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller

From firstController,I try to switch viewController :

```
let player = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WK_player") as? WKViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(player!, animated: true)
```

But WKViewController doesn't appears and directly call his deinit.

It's work well with

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("WK_Play", sender: nil)
```

But with this, dealloc is never get called when I close player and keep existing in memory.

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: is `self.navigationController` `nil` by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue for the memory leak isn't `performSegueWithIdentifier("WK_Play", sender: nil)`. The issue is probably that you have a strong reference somewhere in WK_Play VC which isn't removed thus the VC can't get deallocated.

You could also just try presenting with, but I bet the memory leaks will remain:

```
let player = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WK_player") as? WKViewController
self.presentViewController(player, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Yes, i resolve my problem using switching VC with a UINavigationConroller. Thank's !